# Vim start-up errors

Tags: vim

I have a .vimrc file on my desktop, which I put on github.  Checked it out to my laptop and I get these errors.  Vim 7.4.52, lubuntu

```
Error detected while processing /home/jcg/.vimrc:
line    5:
E117: Unknown function: vundle#begin
line    8:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
line   13:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'bling/vim-airline'
line   16:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
line   19:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'klen/python-mode'
line   21:
E117: Unknown function: vundle#end
```

The .vimrc file:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

" let Vundle manage Vundle -- required!
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'

" The bundles you install will be listed here

" vim-airline status line from github
Plugin 'bling/vim-airline'

" git from within vim
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'

" python mode
Plugin 'klen/python-mode'

call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to come back to my question to perhaps help someone who lands here.
I thought the answer from @Kristjan solved my problem, but it didn't.  Then I found this git repository: https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim

and in step 4 of the README:

Install Plugins:

Launch vim and run :PluginInstall

To install from command line: vim +PluginInstall +qall

This actually was the missing step.  When you copy .vim directory and .vimrc you need to install, and I failed to do this

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Vundle on your laptop. Here are their [installation instructions](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim#quick-start); the part you're missing appears to be

```
git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

The `set rtp` command is adding `~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim` to Vim's path, which lets `vundle#begin()` be found on the next line.

Comment: Thanks.  I actually have a github repo that includes the .vim directory and the files.  But, i did the clone and all is working